# Do MySQL GTIDs get created for all transactions or just those that occur after enabling GTIDs?

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

I have a MySQL database that I'm going to start replicating, and I plan on using GTIDs to do so. The slave will be a brand new virtualized server located overseas.

My question is 2-fold:

1. When I enable GTIDs on the existing master, will GTIDs be created for all previous transactions? Or will they only be created for transactions posted after enabling GTIDs?
2. If yes, can I simply let the slave replay all of the GTIDs at its own pace?(meaning I don't have to sync the slave before enabling replication)

   - I don't care how long it takes the slave to sync (within reason, of course. 2 weeks is probably the max).

I'll be testing this out on some dummy dev servers come Monday or Tuesday, but I figured I'd ask here first.

#### Version and DB Info:

- **Master:** MySQL 5.6.19 on Windows Server 2008R2 (EoL, I know...), but will be upgraded to 5.6.37 before starting replication and will then be upgraded to 5.7.x sometime thereafter.

  - `log_bin` for this server is currently **OFF**.
- **Slave:** MySQL 5.7.19 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS ([verified compatible](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html))
- **Size:** It's probably considered a small database, totalling only about 330GB and something like 2.5 billion rows.

#### Previous Research

I couldn't find anything answering this question in the [GTID docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids.html) nor in the entire [replication docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html).

So far, I've gone through and enabled both binary-log based replication GTID-based replication on various dev servers, but they 1) are very small/empty; 2) had `log_bin` enabled from the start; or 3) were synced before replication was enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, GTIDs will **not** be created for pre-existing data.

This makes sense because, especially without the binlogs, how would the server know what transactions were used to generate the data?